# How to set up the observer for the fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I think I have the View Model set up properly, but I'm having trouble setting up the Observer Any help will be appreciated

The ViewModel

```
class GP1ViewModel() : ViewModel() {

     val gameCardsLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<GameCard>> = MutableLiveData()




         var gameCards: MutableList<GameCard> = ArrayList()
         private var indexOfSelectedPiece: Int? = null



    val images = mutableListOf(
        R.drawable.memorybatcardfront,
        R.drawable.memorycatcardfront,
        R.drawable.memorycowcardfront,
        R.drawable.memorydragonfront,
        R.drawable.memorygarbagemancardfront,
        R.drawable.memoryghostdogcardfront
    )



    init {
        for (image in images) {
            gameCards.add(GameCard(image, imageID = image))
        }

        gameCardsLiveData.value = gameCards
        images.addAll(images)
        images.shuffle()
        Log.d(TAG, "ViewModel Created:")

    }






     fun updatingModels(position: Int) {
        val gameCard = gameCards[position]

        if (gameCard.isFacedUp) return


        if (indexOfSelectedPiece == null) {
            restoreGameCards()
            indexOfSelectedPiece = position

        }
        else {
            checkingForMatch(indexOfSelectedPiece!!, position)
            indexOfSelectedPiece = null
        }
        gameCard.isFacedUp = !gameCard.isFacedUp
    }

    private fun restoreGameCards() {
        for (gameCard in gameCards) {
            if (!gameCard.isMatched) {
              gameCard.isFacedUp = false

            }

        }
    }

    private fun checkingForMatch(position1: Int, position2: Int) {
        if (gameCards[position1].id == gameCards[position2].id) {
            gameCards[position1].isMatched = true
            gameCards[position2].isMatched = true
        }
        else {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                gameCards[position1].isFacedUp = false
                gameCards[position2].isFacedUp = false
            }, 1000)
            Log.d(TAG, "checkingForMatch: the lag is called")
        }
    }


    }
```

The Fragment

```
class GamePlay1Fragment : Fragment() {

//    lateinit var front_anim: AnimatorSet
//    lateinit var back_anim: AnimatorSet

    private lateinit var viewModel: GP1ViewModel
    private lateinit var pieces: List<ImageView>



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: Gameplay1FragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.gameplay1_fragment,
            container, false)



        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(GP1ViewModel::class.java)

        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner


        binding.backButtonView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            v.findNavController().navigate(GamePlay1FragmentDirections.actionGamePlay1FragmentToLobbyFragment())
        }


        viewModel.gameCardsLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        pieces = listOf(binding.card1back, binding.card2back, binding.card3back, binding.card4back,
            binding.card5back,binding.card6back, binding.card7back,
            binding.card8back, binding.card9back, binding.card10back, binding.card11back,
            binding.card12back)

        if (viewModel.gameCards.isEmpty()) {
            viewModel.gameCards = pieces.indices.map { index ->
                GameCard(viewModel.images[index], false, false, viewModel.images[index]).also {
                    GameCard(id, false, false, viewModel.images[index]).isFacedUp = true
                }
            }.toMutableList()
        }




        pieces.forEachIndexed { index, piece ->
            piece.setOnClickListener {

                viewModel.updatingModels(index)



            }
        }

    })



        return binding.root
    }
```

Just not sure how to set up the observer. The observer should be able to control the change in orientation and be able to flip the card on its on after a second. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
binding.viewModel.getGameCardsData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, cards -> {
      // cards will be List<GameCard> and ready to use.
})

// In your viewModel, it is better to access with a getter
private val gameCardsLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<GameCard>> = MutableLiveData()

public fun getGameCardsData() = gameCardsLiveData
```